# How do I parse these string responses to perform some calculations using some extracted values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am integrating my system with a third party API. The integration is more or less done, but I am having a little problem parsing a section of the response. In response, they send me a string, something like the following:

```
EXECUTED @ 9.1539(3.0) was PARTIALLY FILLED @ 9.1531(3.0)
EXECUTED @ 9.1539(3.0)
PARTIALLY FILLED @ 9.16(5.5)
```

Now, I need to parse these responses to get a calculated result as follows:

For: `EXECUTED @ 9.1539(3.0) was PARTIALLY FILLED @ 9.1531(3.5)`

I need to calculate `(9.1539*3.0 + 9.1531*3.5)`

For: `EXECUTED @ 9.1539(3.0)`

I need to calculate `9.1539*3.0`

For: `PARTIALLY FILLED @ 9.16(5.5)`

I need to calculate `9.16*5.5`

I would've posted some code, but I can't figure out where to get started. Some help would be appricated.

Comment: String's have many methods ... see them all [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Comment: Sorry, mistake while copy pasting @Teemu

Comment: `s=>s.match(/\s@\s([\d]+(\.[\d]+|))\(([\d+](\.[\d]+|))\)/g).reduce((a,b)=>a+b.split(/\s@\s/)[1].split(/\)/)[0].split(/\(/).map(Number).reduce((a,b)=>a*b),0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, when you know how to use [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) methods like [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), and [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods like [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) - they're all documented on MDN in the links above

```js
var strs = [
    'EXECUTED @ 9.1539(3.0) was PARTIALLY FILLED @ 9.1531(3.0)',
    'EXECUTED @ 9.1539(3.0)',
    'PARTIALLY FILLED @ 9.16(5.5)'
]

console.log(strs.map(s=>s.match(/\s@\s([\d]+(\.[\d]+|))\(([\d+](\.[\d]+|))\)/g).reduce((a,b)=>a+b.split(/\s@\s/)[1].split(/\)/)[0].split(/\(/).map(Number).reduce((a,b)=>a*b),0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Suggested Solution**

```
let response = `EXECUTED @ 9.1539(3.0) was PARTIALLY FILLED @ 9.1531(3.0)     
EXECUTED @ 9.1539(3.0)
PARTIALLY FILLED @ 9.16(5.5)`;                                                                                                                          

response = response.split(/\n/);                                                                                                                            


for ( let resp of response ) {                                                
    resp = resp.replace(/[^@\(\d\.]/g, "");                                   
    resp = resp.replace(/\(/g, "*");                                          
    resp = resp.replace(/@/g, "+");                                           
    resp = resp.replace(/^\+/, "");                                                                                                                         
    resp = eval(resp);                                                        
    console.log(resp);                                                        
}
```